# Горизонтальный календарь

Tags: java, android, calendar

Есть такой календарь https://github.com/bstrdn/Horizontal-Calendar
Может отображать кружочки под датой, как привязанные к дате события.
Подскажите как добавить свою дату с событием в этот events?

```
public List<CalendarEvent> events(Calendar date) {          
       List<CalendarEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();
       int count = rnd.nextInt(6);
       for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++){
           events.add(new CalendarEvent(Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)), "event"));
            }
       return events;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала создайте List:

```
List<Calendar> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

После этого добавьте ваши даты:

```
Calendar myDate = Calendar.getInstance();
myDate.set(2018, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 18);
myList.add(myDate);
```

Далее вам необходимо добавить код проверки:

```
@Override
public List<CalendarEvent> events(Calendar date) {
       List<CalendarEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();
       int count = rnd.nextInt(6);
       for (Calendar i : myList) {
         if (Utils.isSameDate(date, i)) {
           events.add(new CalendarEvent(Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)), "event"));
         }
       }
       return events;
}
```

Метод `Utils.isSameDate(date, i)` сравнивает дату из календаря с вашей датой из списка.

Надеюсь вам помог мой ответ!

Comment: @Даниил Быстров исправил свой ответ. Проверил. У меня работает, если есть вопросы - прошу.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)